# Question about local flows in vector fields.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, vector-fields

I have a question about the following (this is from Tu's book "Introduction to topological manifolds").

[image]

> From what I understand, if our chart $(U, \phi=(x^1, \dots, x^n))$ is
>   given, then Tu concludes that
>
> $$(x^i \circ c)'(t) = a^i(c(t))$$
>
> Am I interpreting this correctly?
>
> If yes, how does this differential equation imply that we have a
>   unique solution? From what I know, we must be able to write the DE in the form $$y' = f(x,y)$$ to be able to conclude. Clearly we need $y = c$ here but then it is not in the right form. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** After a discussion in the comments, the nature of the confusion has become clear. This answer tries to be very precise about the use of the smooth chart to use Picard-Lindelöf. We have a smooth chart $(U,\phi)$, which consists of an open set $U\subset M$ and a diffeomorphism $\phi:U\rightarrow V\subset \mathbb R^m,$ where $V$ is open in $\mathbb R^m$. The vector field is a map $X:M\rightarrow TM$ such that $X_p\in T_pM$ for all $p\in M$. Since we have a map $\phi:U\rightarrow V$ and its derivative $D\phi:TU\rightarrow TV,$ we may define a new vector field $\phi^*X:V\rightarrow TV$ by $f=D\phi\circ X\circ\phi^{-1}.$ But $TV=V\times \mathbb R^m,$ so $\phi^*X(p)=(p,v)$ can just be described by a map $f:p\mapsto v$, i.e. the unique function $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ such that $\phi^*X(p)=\big(p,f(p)\big)$. Since this is a vector-valued function on an open subset on $\mathbb R^m$, we may apply the Picard-Lindelöf theorem to find some $\epsilon>0$ and a function $y:\mathbb (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ satisfying $y'(t)=f\circ y(t)$ and $y(0)=\phi(c(0))$. Then we define $c:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow M$ by $c(t)=\phi^{-1}\circ y(t).$ This clearly satisfies the prescribed initial conditions. Moreover, you may check that the derivative $c':\mathbb R\rightarrow TM$ satisfies $c'(t)=X_{c(t)}.$ This completes the solution of the differential equation on the manifold $M$.

While it is good to be comfortable with the formality of such arguments, I think that differential geometers usually treat smooth charts in a more hand-waving style. For example, since we know that ODEs of the form $y'=f(y,t)$ can be solved on open subsets of $\mathbb R^m$ and smooth manifolds "look like" open subsets of $\mathbb R^m$, such ODEs can be solved locally on manifolds. But since Picard-Lindelöf also guarantees uniqueness, these local solutions piece together globally (once you move on from integral curves to global flow). I think your wish for formality will serve you well, so long as you also aim to understand things intuitively. I hope the rest of Tu's book goes well for you!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still don't quite see how we apply the theorem. So, we have a system of equations $y_i' = f_i(t,y_1, \dots, y_n), 1 \leq i \leq n$.  In Tu's book, what are the functions $y_i$ and$f_i$ so that we get a solution $c(t)$?

Comment: As you said, we take $y=c$, or equivalently $y_i=c_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. The functions $f_i$ are the $a_i$ given above. These are the components of the vector field on local coordinates. In other words, in the chart $(U,x_1,\dots,x_n),$ the value of $a_i\big(c(t)\big)$ is the component of the tangent vector $X_{c(t)}$ in the $x_i$-direction.

Comment: I'm confused about what you say. Don't we need that the $f_i$'s are functions defined on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: The problem is that $y=c$ is not a real valued function so how can we even get that.

Comment: Thanks. My point was though how you can apply Picard-Lindelöf if you don't know that the functions $f_i$  are defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and how can we take $y=c$ if $c$ is not real-valued!?

Comment: I think I understand! So you define $f=a_i \circ(\phi^i)^{-1}$. Then consider the differential equation $y'=f(y(t))$. This has a solution $y(t)$. I.e. $y'(t)= a_i\circ (\phi^i)^{-1}(y(t))$. Put $c(t)=(\phi^i)^{-1}(y(t))$. The above then implies $(\phi_i\circ c)'(t)= a_i(c(t))$, what we want. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'm new to Math SE and it seems that my discussion in the comments has gone on too long. I've deleted a couple of comments and moved the conclusion of this discussion to the answer itself. To user661541, apart from some misplaced $i$'s, it seems that your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hope you have fun at MSE!